# Date.getSeconds() isn't returning what I'm expecting

Tags: javascript, date

I have the following code:

```
let startDate = new Date(someDateCreated);
let timerDate = new Date(null);
timerDate.setSeconds((currentTime - startDate) / 1000);

console.log(timerDate.getSeconds());
```

Assuming `currentTime` is always now and `someDateCreated` starts at 2 minutes ago, I'd expect to log `120` but it is logging 1. And if I `setInterval` a function that does this every second it just counts `1, 2, 3...` Doing the following

`console.log((currentTime - startDate) / 1000);`

does what I'd expect. Why does `Date.getSeconds()` not give me the seconds I set on it?

Here's a [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmBgjw).

Comment: `setSeconds` sets the seconds part of an `hh:mm:ss` date/time, it must be a value between 0 and 59. "3 o'clock 42 minutes and 120 seconds" isn't a thing.

Comment: @deceze I'm setting the seconds to a number of seconds. `(currentTime - startDate) / 1000` is the value I want. I'm not quite sure follow what you're saying.

Comment: Ooooh, hm. Okay. I know what you're saying now. Thanks.

Comment: @deceze - `.setSeconds()` does accept values greater than 59, in which case it applies the "extra" seconds to increment the minutes (and if necessary the hours, day, month, etc.).

Comment: That's the behavior I'm seeing, @nnnnnn

Comment: So I'm assuming `getSeconds` returns the `0-59` seconds of whatever the time is. That would make the most sense.

Comment: @nnnn Sure, but *"3 o'clock 42 minutes and 120 seconds"* still isn't a thing.

Comment: Yes. The end result of the set operation will always be in that range, and that's what the get returns. @deceze - true. But my point is that despite its name,  setSeconds() can potentially update the rest of the date fields (which is actually a *good* thing if you use it properly).

Answer (score 0):

So tracking this down a bit, while I can `setSeconds()` with values greater than 59 and have the date update the minutes/hours/etc correctly, `getSeconds()` would always seem to return the seconds between `0-59` of whatever the date object is.

`timerDate.getTime() / 1000` is actually what I need.